# How do I take IP addresses from packets in python?

Tags: python, regex

ive tried with regex like this, but i just get [] as the output

```
import socket
import re
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
while True:
    data = str(s.recvfrom(65565))
    pattern = '\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b'
    ips = re.findall(pattern, data)
    print(ips)
```

Comment: What is the content of `data` after calling `s.recvfrom`? Take that, bring up an interactive Python prompt, and test your patterns until you get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Three-four improvements:

1. Use non-capturing-groups (`(?:...)`) instead of capturing groups for parts of the IP address
2. You forgot the raw literal
3. `re.findall()` only yields results for captured groups
4. You want the IP address to be at the end of the string (`$`), is this intended? If so, the last `\b` is meaningless

All of these combined, you could possibly use

```
pattern = r'\b((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.|$)){4})'
#      ---^---
```

And you should be fine. See [**a working demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xc6aiu/4/).